# Dont close mobile phone keyboard on tap specific button

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Lets say the user focuses on an input, the keyboard pops up.

Then he clicks a button, that just shows a tooltip, not important and I would like the keyboard not to close.

I tried this:

```
var dontclosekeyboard = document.getElementById('dontclosekeyboard_element_Id');
```

Then in the the capture phase, meaning i put 3rd parameter to true I try to stop propagation. It sadly does not work.

```
dontclosekeyboard.addEventListener('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation() }, true);
```

I am out of ideas, is there any other solution apart from manually doing a '.focus()' on the currently active element?

Comment: Have you tried setting the focus back to the input field?

Comment: Yes, it kinda works except on iphone but that solution is too complicated and error prone on mobile. From my experience doing 'focus', 'blur' etc on inputs on mobile, programmatically, has a lot of problems. Perhaps another solution is to totally prevent a click is much better and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago showing info-buttons next to form elements. First of all: we finally decided to do that in another way, and work around it.

As soon as you lose focus on your input field the keyboard will be closed and even setting the focus back will cause the keyboard to toggle which is really annoying- with one exception: your tooltip button is also an input field just styled as a button. This way you can set the focus back to the original input without any side effects.

Comment: That would work great actually, it works without flicker on my side regarding the keyboard. Thats really ingenious. Btw, once you 'focus out' be sure to immediatly trigger blur on input again, that way it does not flicker-toggle. Thats what happens on my side atleast.